# angle between hrizontal and a line connecting the center of an oblate ellipse to a point in space

Tags: conic-sections, spherical-coordinates, spheres

I would like to know how I can calculate the angle $\alpha$ in an oblate ellipse similarly to the sphere.

[image]

Comment: You should use everywhere "ellipsoid" instead of "ellipse".